# ITEXT: edit Content in pdf files

Tags: itext

is there a opportunity to edit content in pdf-dokument.
I don't want to print content on the pdf!

My idea:
I have a table in the pdf an want do edit the content of cell one.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's a form you are talking about? What's your workflow? Maybe a pdf doesn't makes sense here.

Comment: *the content of cell one* - usually a PDF does not know about cells, usually, there merely are some lines near to some text bits, but there is no information whether those lines form a text box / cell, whether they underline some text, or whether they merely are background graphics. recognizing tables is the target of whole projects, cf. e.g. [tabula](http://tabula.technology/). And editing is a task which may also prove impossible.